# Change completion behaviour with brace expansion in zsh

Tags: zsh, autocomplete, brace-expansion, oh-my-zsh

I have got used to using tab-autocompleting inside braces without expanding in zsh. This was possible, while I used zsh with a basic grml-config. Since I migrated to oh-my-zsh, I can't reproduce this behaviour.

Example:

```
$ touch dir/{some_file,other_f<TAB>}
```

The behaviour I want:

```
$ touch dir/{some_file,other_file}
```

The behaviour I get:

```
$ touch dir/some_file dir/other_f
```

Instead of autocompleting, a tab expands the braces, defeating the purpose of the brace expansion, whenever I tab for any of the filenames.

I have searched for an answer in the manpages and the zsh-sites for anything relevant, but I couldn't find anything satisfying. Since I am still fresh to zsh, I am not sure, what to look for exactly, though.

I would appreciate any pointers on where to find any explanations relevant to this question.
Thank you in advance for any helpful input!

Comment: That's not the default zsh behavior. It's presumably something that oh-my-zsh does. I don't know what option would do this.

Comment: Are you sure it's not because the braces are closed, when they are still open I get the behavior you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Thor pointed out in his [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48884/change-completion-behaviour-with-brace-expansion-in-zsh#comment68313_48884), the autocompletion in braces only works, until you put the closing brace.

So:

- `touch dir/{some_file,other_f<TAB>`(without the closing brace!) autocompletes the filename, so you get `touch dir/{some_file,other_file`
- `touch dir/{some_file,other_f<TAB>}`(with the closing brace!) expands the braces first, so you get `touch dir/some_file dir/other_f`